# Transparently rewrite/split specific url to different subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to transparently split traffic to two different subdirectories.

For example any url with `/api/...`

Needs to be rewritten to `app/webroot`

Any other url needs to be transparently be mapped to the `site/` subfolder.

I've tried several things attempting to just redirect everything to a single subfolder but can't even get that working, I have an eternal redirect loop.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/webroot [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok, the API reroute works. Initial it wasn't but I realized I was working on a subfolder already - I setup a virtual host so things can be absolute paths. However, the `site` rules aren't working.

Comment: Removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and making the redirect point to `site/$1` allowed this to work. Thanks!